# Dynamically page borders in template when the user go to the next page (different on even and odd pages for duplexing)

Tags: microsoft-word, templates, border, page

what is the best way for the borders of the document to change dynamically when the user go to the next page? Currently I use frame and the page borders. But when the user go to the next page, the frame must change from the left to right. What is the best way to do this.

This is the link to the sample of the document in pdf https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkH1W48iWElCkrZc07atDg4n5Fseog

Comment: How is a PDF supposed to help us understand your problem? Have you tried dividing the document into sections?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will try to be more specific.

Comment: I will try to be more specific. I update the above document, because a notice that the pdf miss some pages. sorry about that.

The document body consist of 2 columns,  even pages has a left column and odd pages has a right column.  What I did is placing a frame  for the left and the right column.
What I want is, when user go to new page,  dynamically the frame must show on the page based on even or odd page layout.
Currently when I go to a new page, the frame I created on the first page are not created on the new page.

I hope that my problem is better explained.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [Different Even and Odd Headers/Footers](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Odd_and_Even)

This is a document setting often coupled with Mirror Margins.

The page border can be a shape or table inserted in the Headers (behind text)

**To repeat something on each page, it needs to be in a header or footer.** That is the purpose of headers and footers. You can use the checkbox in the Header and Footers contextual tab to tell Word to put different ones on even-numbered pages from the one going on odd-numbered pages. This will be background to your page, itself.

You can also use a [StyleRef field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) if you need information in your frame to change based on content in the page itself.

*Note, the links are to further information on my website.*

Comment: (1) Well, that’s the obvious answer — or, at least, the first paragraph of the obvious answer. Have you looked at the document that the OP wants to create? Can you explain how to do ***that**?* (2) As you may have heard, this site likes answers to *contain answers.* Links are certainly OK, but they should support / supplement what you actually post in your answer. Your answer should make sense by itself even if the link goes away. (3) While links are OK, if you link to your own site, you should disclose that when you do so. That goes double when you explicitly solicit money on your site.